# r, search a data frame of values using a dataframe of id pairs to return paired values

Tags: r

I need a way to read a data frame containing two columns of ids, essentially making a data frame of row-wise pairs, that then searches a different data frame using these id pairs and returns their corresponding values.

For instance, I have the following data frame of id pairs:

```
A <- c("a", "b", "a")
B <- c("c", "d", "e")

df_pairs <- data.frame(A, B)

> df_pairs
  A B
1 a c
2 b d
3 a e
```

And I have a data frame of their corresponding values:

```
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
val <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

df_values <- data.frame(id, val)

> df_values
  id val
1  a   1
2  b   2
3  c   3
4  d   4
5  e   5
```

I would like a data frame returned that looks like this:

```
 A B A_value B_value
1 a c       1       3
2 b d       2       4
3 a e       1       5
```

My intention is to incorporate this into an analysis pipeline. Please note the number of pairs and ids will vary in my actual data, so please consider this in your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
## 
## Attaching package: 'dplyr'
## The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
## 
##     filter, lag
## The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
## 
##     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
A <- c("a", "b", "a")
B <- c("c", "d", "e")

df_pairs <- data.frame(A, B)

id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
val <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

df_values <- data.frame(id, val)

left_join(df_pairs, df_values, by = c("A" = "id")) %>%
  left_join(df_values, by =c("B"= "id")) %>%
  select(A, B, A_value = val.x, B_value = val.y)
## Warning: Column `A`/`id` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
## character vector
## Warning: Column `B`/`id` joining factors with different levels, coercing to
## character vector
##   A B A_value B_value
## 1 a c       1       3
## 2 b d       2       4
## 3 a e       1       5
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
A <- c("a", "b", "a")
B <- c("c", "d", "e")
df_pairs <- data.frame(A, B, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
val <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
names(val) <- id

df_quads <- df_pairs
df_quads$A_value <- val[df_pairs$A]
df_quads$B_value <- val[df_pairs$B]
```

to give

```
> df_pairs
  A B
1 a c
2 b d
3 a e

> val
  a   b   c   d   e 
"1" "2" "3" "4" "5" 

> df_quads
  A B A_value B_value
1 a c       1       3
2 b d       2       4
3 a e       1       5
```

though note that your "values" are actually characters

Answer (score 0):

A double merge can also answer this question:

```
merge(
    merge(df_pairs, 
          df_values, 
          by.x=c("A"), 
          by.y=c("id")
          ), 
    df_values, 
    by.x=c("B"), 
    by.y=c("id")
    )
```